# Missing required parameters for route resource show

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I'm passing two parameter to letters.show route. one is locale another is id.

Missing required parameters for [Route: letters.show] [URI: {language}/letters/{letter}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\dstts\resources\views\inc\layout.blade.php)

This error is showing while there's all the required parameters.

My web.php file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function () {

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');



Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('letters', 'LettersController')->middleware('auth');
});
```

Letters Controller show method

```
public function show($lang, $id)
{
         

    $letter = Letter::find($id);
        
    return view('letters.show')->with('letter', $letter);
        }
```

My letters.index page where I have placed letters show button

```
<a class="btn bg-green btn-block btn-xs waves-effect" href="{{ route('letters.show', [app()->getLocale(), $letter->id]) }}"></a>
```

When I click show button in browser address bar it shows correct address: http://dstts.site/en/tasks/1

What I'm missing here?

Comment: why do you have `tasks` in url? it should be `letters`

Comment: You mispelled the url, it would be http://dstts.site/en/letters/1

Comment: I mentioned the wrong url in the question. Anyway http://dstts.site/en/letters/1 is still not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK, nothing is wrong in your code
try to check `$letter->id` that is not `null` or you can test by alternate `$letter->id` with any existing model if it is worked the the wrong will be in `$letter->id`

Comment: $letter->id is not null. Even if it is null there should not be any problem. Because I have viewed a null record before. All of these routes wereworking fine untill I merge my branch with another. Don't know what happened. But this problem occurs only in the routes which require second parameter. letters.index is working fine.